# Removing an element from a List<String[]> not working as expected

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of String arrays which is added to like so:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new String[] {var, lex, valor});
```

When trying to erase one of the String arrays the output is `false` for some reason. Here's how I remove it:

```
data.remove(new String[] {var, lex, valor});
```

I've also tried removing using position, the method is as follows:

```
public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, Integer ii) {
    boolean uno = data.remove(ii);
    System.out.println(uno);
}
```

The output for the method above is `false`. Is there any way to successfully remove the String array from the ArrayList?

Comment: remove by position should work. Are you using the right index? the return value will be the removed array

Comment: I wouldn't expect the first one to work.  I would expect the second to work.  Show us the code for the second one.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the second one is this 
`public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, Integer ii) {
        boolean uno=data.remove(ii);
        System.out.println(uno);
    }`
The output is `false`

Comment: Don't use a capital-I `Integer`.  Use an `int`.

Comment: does it compile? oh.. just realized list.remove() takes object instead of generic type

Comment: `Integer`s are Objects, thus Java uses `remove(Object o)` and cannot find the object, thus returning false.

Comment: When I use `int`, I get `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to boolean`

Comment: The reason you get `incompatible types` is because `remove(int index)` returns the *actual Object at the specified position*, or the removed object, not a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` by String array will not work, as `list.remove` calls `equals()` on the object. In case of array.equals it is just reference comparison (`==`).

Remove by position works and you have to specify the right index as primitive `int`.

```
public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, int ii) {
    String[] uno=data.remove(ii);
    System.out.println(uno);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), you'll see that there are 2 different overloaded methods for `remove`. One takes an Object, the other a primitive integer as position:

> **`remove`**
>
> `public E remove(int index)`
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

The above takes a primitive integer, the below takes an Object:

> **`remove`**
>
> `public boolean remove(Object o)`
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged...

The reason why you see `false` is because you supply the wrapper class of primitive `int`. `Integer` is an *Object*, thus Java uses the method that most closely resembles the way you call it, and in this case you call with an Object parameter. Java then uses method signature `remove(Object o)`, and since the specified `Integer` doesn't exist in the ArrayList, it returns `false`.

Now, the reason why the latter fails is that you create a new String array, thus a new instance. Since `new String[] { var, lex, valor }` and `new String[] { var, lex, valor }` are not *referentially* equal, Java does not find the same Object in the ArrayList and does not remove the item. The solution is to use primitive `int`:

```
public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, int ii) {
    String[] uno = data.remove(ii); //Make sure to use String[], as different types are returned
    System.out.println(uno);
}
```

Java will then use the method that takes in a primitive integer because you pass a primitive integer. The reason why you see `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to boolean` is because `remove(int index)` returns *the actual Object at the position specified*, or the removed object, not a `boolean` like `remove(Object o)` does.

Answer (score 3):

```
data.remove(new String[]{var, lex, valor});
```

Will never work because even if the arrays contain the same thing, they are not equal to each other, and the array will not be found in the list.

---

```
public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, Integer ii) {
    boolean uno=data.remove(ii);
    System.out.println(uno);
}
```

Will not work because you pass it an `Integer` instead of an `int`. An `Integer` is an object, so it is searching the list for that object. Change it to:

```
public void eliminarPos(String var, String lex, String valor, int ii) {
    data.remove(ii);
}
```