# remove() metthod of ArrayList not working for ArrayList of int array (ArrayList<int[]>) in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying use remove(Object o) of ArrayList for remove a int array, but this not remove. How can remove int array with remove(Object o)?

```
package remove;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<int[]> test = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        test.add(new int[] {0,1});
        test.add(new int[] {0,2});
        test.add(new int[] {0,3});
        test.add(new int[] {0,4});
        test.add(new int[] {0,5});
        test.add(new int[] {0,6});
        test.add(new int[] {0,7});

        test.remove(new int[] {0,4});

        for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(test.get(i)[0] + " " + test.get(i)[1]);
        }

    }
}
```

This is out:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901616/removing-an-element-from-a-liststring-not-working-as-expected

Comment: try  test.remove(3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are different object if you `System.out.println(new int[] {0,4}==new int[] {0,4});` the result will be `false`

Try to remove like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<int[]> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 1 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 2 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 3 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 4 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 5 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 6 });
    test.add(new int[] { 0, 7 });
    int[] removeArr = new int[] { 0, 4 };
    test.removeIf(p -> Arrays.equals(p, removeArr));

    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(test.get(i)[0] + " " + test.get(i)[1]);
    }
}
```

, output

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 5
0 6
0 7
```

Comment: You can also use `int[] toRemove = {0,4}; test.removeIf(a -> Arrays.equals(a, toRemove));`, which would definitely be easier to write for longer arrays, and can be used for variable-sized arrays.

Comment: If would be better to do it as I showed, so as not to create the comparison `{ 0, 4 }` array 7 times.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it by running a for loop on all of the test elements and delete this element by doing this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<int[]> test = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    test.add(new int[] {0,1});
    test.add(new int[] {0,2});
    test.add(new int[] {0,3});
    test.add(new int[] {0,4});
    test.add(new int[] {0,5});
    test.add(new int[] {0,6});
    test.add(new int[] {0,7});
    for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
        if(test.get(i)[0]==0 && test.get(i)[1]==4){
            test.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(test.get(i)[0] + " " + test.get(i)[1]);
    }

}
```

good luck!

Comment: You need to decrement `i` when you remove, otherwise it skips an element.

Comment: Try changing `{0,5}` to `{0,4}` so there are two consecutive arrays of `{0,4}`. Only one of them will be removed, because the second one is **skipped**. Now change *all* of them to `{0,4}`, and 4 of the 7 are removed, leaving 3 behind. --- Now, if you intended the code to be consistent with [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) *(removes the **first** occurrence of the specified element)*, then you need to add `break` instead of decrementing `i`. --- Either way, the current code is flawed.

Comment: wow thank you for correcting me! i will edit my comment now